# BigBlueButton sound issue - can't join with audio neither listening (ICE error 1004)

Tags: html5-audio, sip, freeswitch, bigbluebutton

I am using BigBlueButton with canvas. I installed it using the script provided on their Github page, namely:

```
wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -w -a -v xenial-22 -s bbb.example.com -e info@example.com
```

The problem is whenever I create a conference and join it. I couldn't use the audio neither listening.

When clicking on join with microphone, an error pops-up saying:

```
Failure on call (reason=ICE error) (error 1004)
```

And when I click on the Listen only, nothing happens.

I consulted the logs but nothing useful, I suspected some sound errors due to host configuration but I am not able to get things clear. Maybe some of you could have an idea about which logs to consult.

I suspect it is a problem related to FreeSWITCH, I followed a setup here about setting up FreeSWITCH with a firewall (even though I don't use a firewall but BBB config indicates that it considers a firewall) but nothing changed.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @younes-zeboudj were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, by commenting a line in app/models/bigbluebutton_conference.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I fixed this by commenting the line containing (voiceBridge=...) In app/models/bigbluebutton_conferenfe.rb.

Answer (score 0):

You saved my life. The file younes is talking about is from Canvas LMS. If you followed the official installation instructions, this file should be in `/var/canvas/app/models/big_blue_button_conference.rb`. You will need to restart the application (or if you don't know how, the server) for the change to take effect.

The line to comment in context:

```
current_host = URI(settings[:default_return_url] || "http://www.instructure.com").host
    send_request(:create, {
      :meetingID => conference_key,
      :name => title,
#      :voiceBridge => format("%020d", self.global_id),
      :attendeePW => settings[:user_key],
      :moderatorPW => settings[:admin_key],
      :logoutURL => (settings[:default_return_url] || "http://www.instructure.com"),
      :record => settings[:record] ? "true" : "false",
      :welcome => settings[:record] ? t("This conference may be recorded.") : "",
      "meta_canvas-recording-ready-user" => recording_ready_user,
      "meta_canvas-recording-ready-url" => recording_ready_url(current_host)
    }) or return nil
```